# Having maven 3.0.4 and GIT work

Tags: git, maven, ssh

I try to make a checkout from maven. I have the following pom.xml content :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>server</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/build</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.gitignore</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>                
                <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
                <checkoutDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/checkout</checkoutDirectory>
                <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/checkout</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>check-out-master</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>checkout</goal>
                    </goals>
                                <configuration>
                        <servers>
                            <server>staging</server>
                        </servers>
                    </configuration>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- THIRD PARTY DEPENDENCIES -->
<!-- ... -->

<!-- GIT -->

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://10.0.50.12/opt/git-repos/server.git</connection>
    <url>scm:git:ssh://10.0.50.12/opt/git-repos/server.git</url>

    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://10.0.50.12/opt/git-repos/server.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

In my settings.xml I have the following content :

```
<server>
    <id>staging</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```

I can't get it work, nor can I obtain a prompt for the password.

At the execution I obtain this :

```
[INFO] --- maven-scm-plugin:1.0:checkout (check-out-master) @ server ---

[INFO] Removing C:\workspace\server\server\target\checkout

[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git clone ssh://10.0.50.12/opt/git-repos/server.git C:\workspace\server\server\target\checkout"

[INFO] Working directory: C:\workspace\server\server\target
```

And it is stuck at this point ...
I guess it is waiting for the password.

Does anybody know a solution to get it work with the password or at least with a prompt for password ?

**EDIT**

Today I have made a simple test : I ran the mvn compile command from linux and I got a prompt for the git password. Maybe I should need a ssh agent

Comment: Can you successfully clone from the command-line?

Comment: Yes everything is ok from windows command-line
I mean, in this case I have a prompt for ssh password

Comment: Run maven with `-X -e` and output to a file. This might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: I have already done that and I get the same result : stuck at the end, probably waiting for the ssh password. It is just like he does not find the credentials for the ssh connection.

Comment: Are you trying this under the same user?

Comment: Yes, I run the mvn compile command in windows with the same user name in linux. But even if it was not the case I guess the username and password in settings.xml are given for that, aren't they ?

Comment: The username and password have no effect on the scm plugin. You are mistaken. They are used for the deployment of artifacts.

Comment: Ok thanks for this information. So how could I give the SSH credentials to the scm plugin ?

Comment: um... git ssh does not use credentials. it uses ssh keys. you're not supposed to use ssh credentials with git, ever. if you see a prompt for password with ssh access it means that you have failed the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure git is properly set up on the machine on which you're running this (have the name and e-mail setting defined). Then try a checkout from the console first. If that works, it should work for Maven as well. As you can see, it's executing an external process.

If this fails, try running the command Maven is invoking for git as it's printing it.

Comment: I have done it and everything works fine. But through maven it still doesn't.

Comment: I can see here [link](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/site/site-deployment.html) that Maven currently does not contain an SSH client, so you need to install one yourself. Many Linux distributions come with OpenSSH. Windows users can use Cygwin with the optional installation of OpenSSH. Do I need cygwin ?

Comment: Well, of course you will need an ssh client! You need to have one installed. Like I mentioned, Maven is invoking git as an external application. Git git requires ssh in your case.

Comment: Ok I understand but when I run the git command in my window "cmd.exe" then everything works. It does not only from maven itself. That is why I wanted to know how to give credentials to maven for git.